# How to make a text filter in java?

Tags: java, string, text, filter

I am trying to make a filter for internet page. It should download a page, and then find images in code. I already have downloading part, and html code goes in String. But i have no idea how to filter this code. I guess program should delete everything except parts like this "img id="image" src="https:/....jpg"", and then delete everything except link. So, finally it should be just a string with links to images. Is it any way to filter code like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) seems like a relevant library. It will even handle downloading the document for you.

Since you've already loaded your page into a String, you can do something like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements images = doc.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

You can grab attributes from individual an `Element` by invoking the `attr` function:

```
Element image = images.get(0);
String href = image.attr("href");
```

Comment: Thank you, that is really useful. But it still gives me element like this: img id="" class="" src="" Rating: "" Score: "" User: "" Date: "" width="" height="". How can i delete this?

Comment: Oh, i have done it by this: `String linkHref = link.attr("href");`

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect this.